# Why defining copy constructor gives me error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'obj&' to an rvalue of type 'obj'?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#define Nbodies 3

class Assembly {
public:
    // initializing constructor
    Assembly(double _dataA)
        : data(_dataA), AssA(nullptr), AssB(nullptr) { }

    // double argument copy constructor
    Assembly(Assembly &A, Assembly&B)
        : AssA(&A), AssB(&B) {
        data = A.data * B.data;
    }

    // single argument copy constructor - generates errors once uncommented
/*
    Assembly(Assembly &A)
        : data(A.data), AssA(&A), AssB(&A) {
        // initialize other members of this class here
    }
*/
    double data;
private:
    // these are const pointers to non-const objects of a type Assembly
    Assembly *const AssA, *const AssB;
};

int main() {
    std::array<double, Nbodies> datas = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

    // Initilize first branch of the binary tree
    std::vector<Assembly> base_assembly;
    for (int i = 0; i < Nbodies; i++) {
        base_assembly.emplace_back(datas[i]);
    }

    // Binary tree assembly - MWE (for general case, I'm using nested for loop)
    Assembly AssemblyAB = Assembly(base_assembly[0], base_assembly[1]);
    Assembly AssemblyC = Assembly(base_assembly[2]);
    Assembly AssemblyS = Assembly(AssemblyAB, AssemblyC);

    std::cout << AssemblyS.data << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm working on a program that generates a binary try recursively. When I have a branch with an odd number of elements, I need to "rewrite" an element to a lower branch. For this, I use a copy constructor since I need to initialize additional members of the class (I'm using the Eigen library, and some operations can not be done as a one-liner in the initialization list).

My problem arose when I defined a singe argument copy constructor. I get the following error:

> .../mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7:
>   error:
>
> cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'Assembly&' to
>   an rvalue of type 'Assembly'

Why defining a single argument copy constructor generates such an error? Note that in the case of a two-argument copy constructor the are no errors at all.

Comment: A copy constructor has this kind of signature:  `Foo(Foo const&)`.  A `Foo(Foo&)` is not a good copy constructor.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. However, this means that I have a semi-copy constructor since I can't resign from defining references `&A` and `&B` inside them. The problem remains the same.

Comment: @Eljay -- according to the standard, a copy constructor takes an argument of type `Foo&`, `const Foo&`, `volatile Foo&`, or `const volatile Foo&`. So `Foo(Foo&)` is a perfectly good copy constructor.

Comment: The error message was almost certainly longer than what's quoted here. It should have had a backtrace through the various calls that led to that failure. That would tell you where in your code the problem got started.

Comment: Incidentally, there is no such thing as a "two-argument copy constructor". A copy constructor takes exactly one argument, or, if it takes more than one argument, all arguments except the first must have default values. A copy constructor copies **one object**.

Comment: @PeteBecker • "If a class X only has a copy constructor with a parameter of type X&, an initializer of type const X or volatile X cannot initialize an object of type (possibly cv-qualified) X."  That's what makes `Foo(Foo&)` not a _good_ copy constructor, because of its limiting constraint.  If the use case does not need that capability, then it is okay, but in the OP's case that capability was attempted to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical copy constructor takes `const T&`, or in this case `const Assembly&`.
Since you don't have that, there is no way for standard library containers such as `std::vector` to copy your type, which it would need to do if it ever needs to reallocate the array (e.g. to make it bigger).

However, `std::vector<T>` where `T` has a noexcept move constructor will use the move constructor instead, thus avoiding the problem of not having a copy constructor.

Thus the following addition allows this to work:

```cpp
Assembly(Assembly&&) noexcept = default; // generate a noexcept move constructor
```

Note that this will result in the newly-constructed object also pointing to the same `AssA` and `AssB` objects.

As a side note, I would recommend renaming those to `AsmA` and `AsmB` if only to deter snickering.

Edit:

At the very root, the problem is with that single parameter `Assembly&` constructor, which is causing the copy constructor to not be implicitly generated. The similarity to the copy constructor is also bad due to being unintuitive. `Assembly thing = other;` would actually call the weird `Assembly&`constructor when you would expect it to just copy. Thus the best answer to the problem is just to get rid of it.

Option 1: When you want that behavior, just use the 2 parameter constructor and pass the same object twice.

Option 2: Make it a tag constructor:

```cpp
// the tag type we'll use to select the weird constructor
inline struct same_asm_t {} same_asm; // not sure what version of C++ you're on; if this doesn't work remove inline and define in a cpp file elsewhere

// define this as a tag constructor (take some other "tag" type as a param for overload resolution)
Assembly(Assembly &A, same_asm_t) : data(A.data), AssA(&A), AssB(&A) {}

// use it like this, where other is an instance of Assembly
Assembly thing(other, same_asm);
```

Comment: I followed your advice by adding this line above the definition of said constructor and it worked well with above MRE, but in my main code I got:
`error: use of deleted function 'Assembly::Assembly(Assembly&&)'`,

`info: 'Assembly::Assembly(Assembly&&) noexcept' is implicitly deleted because its exception-specification does not match the implicit exception-specification'`
Once I removed the last part, i.e. with `Assembly(Assembly&&) noexcept` it worked even there.

Comment: Your insight was very helpful! Unfortunately, this didn't solve another error (which was also present from the beginning):
`error: binding reference of type 'Assembly&' to 'const Assembly' discards qualifiers`.

I believe that my implementation of stl simply does not support such an approach, however, I'm thinking, whether I should reformulate the question to address this issue as well.